How to set testLogging events in Kotlin gradle?
What is the Kotlin version of this code snippet from Groovy Gradle?
test {
    testLogging {
        events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
    }
}

I tried setting the testLogging events inside tasks.test, but it gives a compile-time error.
tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    testLogging.events = listOf("PASSED", "FAILED", "SKIPPED")
}


I also found another alternative for Murat's solution.
tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    testLogging.events(TestLogEvent.PASSED, TestLogEvent.FAILED, TestLogEvent.SKIPPED)
}

